# How to create circles starting with points and attributes (diameter, lat/long)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, polygon, buffer

I have a point shapefile with attributes (diameter, latitude  and longitude). For each point in that file, I want to create a polygon (circle) described by those attributes. The new shapefile should have circles of described diameter.

I am using ArcGIS 10.0.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Can you use a scripted solution, or do you need to use existing tools within ArcGIS?

Comment: Usually ArcGIS applications liek ArcMap/ArcCatalog render each layer with diffrent symbologies allocated to each feature categories depending to one or more attributes(See UniqueValueRenderer in ArcMap for example).For example ArcMap can put a circle in each lat/long with different color and the color can depend on the diameter of feature(but all circles with same size).If you want different circle diameter for each circle feature I think you have to write code for a feature layer renderer.Let me know if you want jump into ArcObject programming so I put some sample code here.

Comment: @Reza This isn't a rendering issue, it's just a simple buffer. Using ArcObjects to solve this would be needless complication.

Comment: Vince,My answer was before user3526370 made his question clear.The second answer I put after that,using ArcToolbox/Analysis Tools/Proximity/Buffer is simple and worked for me easily.

Answer (score 1):

Use the buffer tool. You can specify an attribute field as the buffer distance. the field type must be numeric http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/buffer.htm

If all you want is to draw the symbols, you can use the appropriate symbol renderer settings described here. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/map/working-with-layers/using-proportional-symbols.htm

Comment: hi

    i make my question more clear, I want the individual points to be converted into polygon Feature type (with given diameter, lat and long). So that in the attribute table i should get the shape as polygon instead of point. 

NOTE: Feature type should be converted from point to polygon for each  data and a circle should be drawn based on the given parameters.

Comment: Yup.just use buffer, the tool output will be a polygon feature class.

Answer (score 0):

A shape file can have only one "Shape" field and in your case It is already filled with Point geometry data.You have to create a new shape file with Polygon geometry type.ArcToolbox(ArcMap/ArcCatalog already have this tool).you can use ArcToolbox/Analysis tools/Proximity/Buffer. use your shape file as "Input features" and type the name of new shape file in "Output feature class".Instead of "linear unit",select "Field" and in popup menu under this option,select the numeric field that contains diameter.Now click Ok, and ArcToolbox creates a new shape file for you that has desired circles.
[image]

Comment: thanks a lot, this helped me to convert my point feature to polygon also. thanks once again